Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$ with $a_n = \big ( \frac{n}{n+1} \big ) ^{n^2}$
How should I go about proving:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1 \quad \text{ with } \quad a_n = \bigg( \frac{n}{n+1} \bigg) ^{n^2}
\end{equation}
Using a graphical calculator, I can see that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \big( \frac{n+1}{n+2} \big) ^{(n+1)^2}\big( \frac{n+1}{n} \big) ^{n^2}$ is monotone decreasing and converges to roughly $0.366$ .
I thought it's easiest to prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
Which leads to this expression:
\begin{equation}
  \bigg( \frac{n+1}{n+2} \bigg) ^{(n+1)^2}\bigg( \frac{n+1}{n} \bigg) ^{n^2} < \frac{1}{2} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
2(n+1)^{(n+1)^2+n^2} < (n+2)^{(n+1)^2}n^{n^2}
\end{equation}
Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758957/relations-between-the-root-test-and-the-ratio-test, one has to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ which is much easier.

@xpaul I would agree if we knew that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ has a limit (e.g. if we had proven $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is monotone, as OP has observed).  Is there a way to use that method without a separate proof the limit exists?

If you continue the Taylor expansion as used by @Anne Bauval, you will have $$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac 1 e \Big(1+\frac{1}{3
n^2} +O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)  \Big)$$

It will be easier to solve a related problem first.  To this end, note that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}} &= \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{(n-1)^2} \\
&= \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{-2n}\left(\frac{n-1}n\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^{-2n}\left(\frac{n-1}n\right) \\
&= \left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\right)^{-2}\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)
\end{align*}$$
so that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} = e^{-1} \cdot (e^{-1})^{-2} \cdot 1 = e.$$
To finish:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n-1}/a_n} = \frac1e < 1.$$

$$\begin{align}\ln a_n&=n^2\ln\frac n{n+1}\\&=-n^2\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\\&=-n^2\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\\&=-n+\frac12+o(1)
\end{align}$$
hence
$$\begin{align}\ln\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\left(-n-1+\frac12+o(1)\right)-\left(-n+\frac12+o(1)\right)\\&=-1+o(1)\end{align}$$
i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e^{-1}.$$
